# Xamarin.Forms and App Center: unable to install iOS release on iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, iphone-5, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I'm working on a **Xamarin.Forms app** that I would like to deploy for some testers through **App Center**.

In **Visual Studio**, I'm able to build and deploy the app on a **iPhone 5s** simulator, even if the **iOS version is 11.4**.

In the `info.plist` the `Minimum system version` is set to **8.0**. In the `iOS Build` settings, the `SDK Version` is set to **default**. On my machine, the current version of **XCode** is **12.1**.

On **App Center**, I've managed the **Build Configuration** like this:

- Configuration: Release
- SDK version: Xamarin.iOS.14.4
- Xcode version: 12.2
- Build scripts: None
- Build type: Device build

When the build is finished, I'm able to install the release on **iPhone XS** (iOS 14.2) or **iPhone 6** (iOS 12.4.8), but not on the **iPhone 5s** (iOS 12.4.9).

I get this the error message "***The developers are working on a version for your device***".

However, I've added the **App Center** profile on each devices, and the **iPhone 5s** appears in my **registered devices**.

On **App Center**, I've tried to use older configuration for the **Build Configuration**:

- SDK version: Xamarin.iOS.14.2
- Xcode version: 12.1

***But the result is the same. Is this normal?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/auto-provisioning)

> If we detect that the device that the tester is using isn't on the
> list of provisioned devices for the .ipa they want to download, then
> we show the message "The developers are working on a version for your
> device."

Comment: Hi @Jason, you're right I've just seen this in the "Devices" tab. After having re-signed the Provisioning Profile directly in AppCenter for the iPhone 5S, I'm now able to install the app!

Comment: What do you mean by "re-signed the Provisioning Profile directly in AppCenter"?  How do you do this?